# AS3 Sound recording directly in mp3 format

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, wav, shinemp3encoder

I use AS3 to record sound and store it locally .wav. Is it possible record directly in mp3 format not .wav. I saw shineMP3 encoder. How i can use that to encode directly to mp3, not converting after record in wav?

Comment: I don't know how to use MP3 encoder. I need some instruction.

Comment: Well on https://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/#Usage there are some instructions. You need to get the byteArray from your `wav` file and use that to convert to mp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I recorded.wav then convert it without interval to MP3 with ShineMP3Encoder after trying for days.